# How to add horizontal, then vertical shorts in circuitikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz, intersections

I've noticed that in circuitikz, while the regular tikz lines of horizontal-then-vertical (-|) and vertical-then-horizontal (|-) lines work fine when joining two items with different absolute coordinates. However, the short lines don't seem to allow this (I assume this is because they are a simple dipole element).

For example, the following gives what I want visually

```
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
    %Draw stimulus op-amp
    \draw (0,0) node[op amp] (opamp_in) {};
    % Draw input signal
    \draw (opamp_in.+) to[short] ++(-1,0)
        to[sinusoidal voltage source] ++(0,-2) 
        node[ground] {};
    % Draw feedback
    \draw (opamp_in.-) to[short] ++(0, 1)
        -| (opamp_in.out)
        to[short, *-] ++(1,0)
        node[right] {$V_{out}$};
\end{circuitikz}
```

However it uses the tikz lines for the joining line, so it looks a little bit different. Is there a better or preferred way to do this? Is there some way to make a coordinate that uses the x position from some relative coordinates, and the y position from the other so I can find that corner point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is the coordinate idiom `(A|-B)`, which means "on the vertical of `A` and on the horizontal of `B`", or the dual `(B-|A)`. So I normally use for the feedback:

```latex
\draw (0,0) node[op amp](A1){}
    (A1.-) to[short] ++(0,1) coordinate(tmp) 
    to[R] (tmp -| A1.out) to[short] (A1.out);
```

Notice that it works only for named coordinates, you can't say `(tmp |- (1,0))`.

...but I am not sure why you find that `--` and `short` are different... are you sure it is not a rendered (PDF viewer) glitch?

Comment: Actually, you can use `(tmp |- 1,0)`.  Thanks to @marmot for setting me straight.

Comment: Ah, thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for!